# Backbutton in ActionBar Android Appcelerator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcelerator

Im noob in framework appcelerator and I have a simple problem in android. I dont know how put the backbutton in ActionBar like this
[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeyhp.png)

This button does not appear to me. I used heavywindow.
android sdk-version 27
SDK Titanium 7.0.0.GA

Comment: simply add this line to your code
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
or if using AppCompactActivity
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Action Bar like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window title="Action Bar Title">
        <ActionBar platform="android" displayHomeAsUp="true" onHomeIconItemSelected="close"></ActionBar>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

You can even add Subtitle, Menu Items, Overflow Menu, icons, & even custom views.

Read more about using **[Action Bar in Titanium here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar)**

For more control over ActionBar for full customizations, Titanium has introduced Toolbar in SDK 6.2.0 - **[Read about Titanium Android Toolbar here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Toolbar)**

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome! mark this answer as accepted so other users can refer this answer.

Answer (score -1):

write this in onCreate

```
   {
          getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
          getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

override onOptionsItemSelected method

```
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           switch (item.getItemId()){

              case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
  }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Before writing answers, do read questions properly. User is asking to add ActionBar in Appcelerator, not in native Android.